# Hamel Dimension of Infinite Dimensional Separable Banach Space

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, banach-spaces, normed-spaces

I was trying to show this result. I have seen proofs that show that the dimension is at least $\mathfrak{c}$, however, I'm unable to prove that it is exactly $\mathfrak{c}$. The last line of this article is unclear. How does separability imply that dimension is $\mathfrak{c}$? [image]

Comment: You can also use the Baire category theorem to prove that any infinite dimensional Banach space has an uncountable hamel basis, hint: proof by contradiction.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If $X$ is separable, it has a countable dense subset $A$.  Every point of $X$ is a limit of some sequence in $A$, and there are only $|A|^{|\mathbb{N}|}=\mathfrak{c}$ different sequences in $A$.  So $|X|\leq\mathfrak{c}$.  A Hamel basis for $X$ is a subset of $X$, and so any Hamel basis has at most $\mathfrak{c}$ elements.

Comment: I want to ask that do we assume x_n’s to be unit or smt? Since otherwise how do we know that the series of x_t converges?