# Isometric and isomorphic spaces are isometrically isomorphic

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

> Let $(X, \|\cdot\|_1)$ and $(Y, \|\cdot\|_2)$ be two normed spaces over $\mathbb{F} \in \{\mathbb{R}, \mathbb{C}\}$ such that:
>
> 1. $X$ and $Y$ are isomorphic as vector spaces.
> 2. There exists a bijective norm-preserving map $\psi : X \to Y$,  **not necessarily linear**.
>
> Can we conclude that $X$ and $Y$ are isometrically isomorphic?

I'm aware of the [Mazur-Ulam theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mazur%E2%80%93Ulam_theorem) (not of its proof, though), which implies that $\psi$ must be affine if $X$ and $Y$ are real.

Using it, we can, even without assuming $(1)$, conclude that if there exists an isometry (distance-preserving, not norm-preserving!) between $X$ and $Y$ then there exists a *linear* isometry (also distance-preserving) between $X$ and $Y$, as noted in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/81086/144766). This, however, does not imply that $X$ and $Y$ are isometrically isomorphic (i.e. it does not imply the existence of a linear norm-preserving map).

Can we strengthen this to a norm-preserving isomorphism with $(1)$?

Comment: I think an isomorphism between vector spaces  must be linear to preserve the stracture.

Comment: @MariosGretsas Yes, there exists a linear bijection $\phi : X \to Y$ which is the isomorphism from $(1)$. However, $\psi$ is unrelated to $\phi$.

Comment: Note that such a $\psi $ exists between $\Bbb R^2$ and $\Bbb R^3$, for example, simply because spheres have continuum cardinality.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen You would bijectively map vectors from $S^1(0,R)$ to $S^2(0,R)$? Yes, that seems to work. However, $\mathbb{R^2}$ and $\mathbb{R^3}$ are not isomorphic as vector spaces.

Comment: How about $\ell^3$ and $\ell^2$? The map $u \mapsto u \, \sqrt{|u|}$ (applied coefficient-wise) is bijective and norm-preserving. Both spaces should also be isomorphic as vector spaces (using a Hamel basis).

Comment: @mechanodroid: But the Mazur-Ulam theorem needs a distance-preserving map (and not only a norm-preserving map).

Comment: @gerw You are right, Mazur-Ulam is not applicable here. Could you elaborate on the vector space isomorphism of $\ell^3$ and $\ell^2$?

Comment: @mechanodroid: I am not absolutely sure about this. But AC shows that $\ell^2$ and $\ell^3$ both have a Hamel basis and I would guess that these bases have the same cardinality. Hence, you can map one basis to the other and extend by linearity.

Comment: @gerw: [The Hamel dimension of every infinite-dimensional separable Banach space is $\mathfrak{c}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1899365/hamel-dimension-of-infinite-dimensional-separable-banach-space).  It might be easier to run this argument with $\ell^1$ and $\ell^2$ since it's simpler to show they are not isometrically isomorphic.

Comment: @NateEldredge Thanks, I'm convinced that this is a counterexample. How would we prove that $\ell^1$ and $\ell^2$ are not isometrically isomorphic?

Comment: @mechanodroid Parallelogram identity fails in $\ell^1$. Or, the unit ball of $\ell^1$ is not strictly convex (its boundary contains line segments). If you are convinced that the argument works, please post an answer.

Comment: @Michelle: Oh yeah, and I guess that is just as easy for $\ell^2$ versus $\ell^3$.  I was thinking that for $\ell^1$ versus $\ell^2$, it is easier to show there is not even any linear homeomorphism.

Comment: @NateEldredge You mean there isn't even a bounded linear bijection between $\ell^1$ and $\ell^2$? How to prove that?

Comment: @mechanodroid: For instance, $\ell^2$ is reflexive and $\ell^1$ isn't.  $(\ell^2)^*$ is separable and $(\ell^1)^*$ is not.  Every weakly convergent sequence in $\ell^1$ converges strongly (see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/42609/strong-and-weak-convergence-in-ell1) but this is false in $\ell^2$.  Etc, etc, etc.

Comment: @NateEldredge Amazing, I wasn't aware that linear homeomorphisms would preserve all those properties.

Comment: @mechanodroid: It basically flows from the fact that the adjoint of a linear homeomorphism is a linear homeomorphism.  See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/346560/show-t-is-invertible-if-t-is-invertible-where-t-in-bx-t-in-bx/346640#346640